# How to install a python module in a docker container

Tags: python, docker

My Docker knowledge is very poor, I have Docker installed only because I would use freqtrade, so I followed this simple HOWTO

https://www.freqtrade.io/en/stable/docker_quickstart/

Now , all freqtrade commands run using docker , for example this

```
D:\ft_userdata\user_data>docker-compose run --rm freqtrade backtesting --config user_data/cryptofrog.config.json --datadir user_data/data/binance --export trades --stake-amount 70 --strategy CryptoFrog -i 5m
```

Well , I started to have problems when I would had try this strategy
https://github.com/froggleston/cryptofrog-strategies
for freqtrade . This strategy requires Python module finta .
I understood that the Python module finta should be installed in my Docker container
and NOT in my Windows system (it was easy "pip install finta" from console!).

Even if I tried to find a solution over stackoverflow and google, I do no understand how to do this step (install finta python module in freqtrade container).
after several hours I am really lost.

Someone can explain me in easy steps how to do this ?

Freqtrade mount point is
D:\ft_userdata\user_data

Comment: Please, post your docker file.

Comment: no idea , where should I find it ?

Comment: Typically you'd whatever dependency to a `Pipfile` or `setup.py` in your source tree, using standard Python packaging tools; run `pip freeze` if needed to regenerate a `requirements.txt` file; then re-run `docker build` to get a new image.  You do not generally install packages in running containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get bash from your container with this command:

```
docker-compose exec freqtrade bash
```

and then:

```
pip install finta
```

OR
run only one command:

```
docker-compose exec freqtrade pip install finta
```

If the above solutions didn't work, You can run `docker ps` command and get `container id` of your container. Then

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash
pip install finta
```

Comment: I tried it , it returns nothing and the problem continues.
PS C:\Users\graziano> docker-compose exec freqtrade pip install finta
PS C:\Users\graziano>

Comment: run `docker ps` and print result here

Comment: D:\ft_userdata\user_data>docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                  PORTS                      NAMES
385758e10aca   freqtradeorg/freqtrade:stable   "freqtrade trade --l…"   40 minutes ago   Up Less than a second   127.0.0.1:8080->8080/tcp   freqtrade

Comment: run `docker exec -it 385758e10aca bash` and then `pip install finta`.

Comment: it worked however when I execute D:\ft_userdata\user_data>docker-compose run --rm freqtrade backtesting --datadir user_data/data/binance --export trades --stake-amount 70 --strategy CryptoFrog -i 5m  I continue to receive the error  No module named 'finta'

Comment: Each time you run `docker-compose run...` your docker container rebuild and new id set to your container. You need run each time `docker ps` and get `container id`, Then `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash` and `pip install finta`

Comment: very well ok I will try it

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your own docker image that has finta installed. Luckily you can build on top of the standard freqtrade docker image.

First make a `Dockerfile` with these two lines in it

```
FROM freqtradeorg/freqtrade:stable
RUN pip install finta
```

Then build the image (calling the new image `myfreqtrade`) by running the command

```
docker build -t myfreqtrade .
```

Finally change the docker-compose.yml file to run your image by changing the line

```
image: freqtradeorg/freqtrade:stable
```

to

```
image: myfreqtrade
```

And that should be that.

Comment: after doing this if I pull freqtrade I receive this

ERROR: for freqtrade  pull access denied for myfreqtrade, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
ERROR: pull access denied for myfreqtrade, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: What should I do to pull myfreqtrade

Comment: I've never had to do anything special to be able to pull images. I think it might have to do with your Docker installation.

Comment: if I use docker I receive exactly the same error .

Comment: can you run the command `docker pull freqtradeorg/freqtrade:stable` without errors? If not, what error does it give?

Comment: yes it works , but I need to update the myfreqtrade docker image

Comment: If you've made the Dockerfile and run the build command (remember the dot at the end), you should be able to see `myfreqtrade` listed if you run a `docker image ls` command.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get our Python code running in a container is to pack it as a Docker image and then run a container based on it.
[image]

To generate a Docker image we need to create a Dockerfile that contains instructions needed to build the image. The Dockerfile is then processed by the Docker builder which generates the Docker image. Then, with a simple docker run command, we create and run a container with the Python service.

An example of a Dockerfile containing instructions for assembling a Docker image for Python service installing `finta` is the following

```
# set base image (host OS)
FROM python:3.8

# install dependencies
RUN pip install finta

# command to run on container start
CMD [ "python", "-V" ]
```

For each instruction or command from the Dockerfile, the Docker builder generates an image layer and stacks it upon the previous ones. Therefore, the Docker image resulting from the process is simply a read-only stack of different layers.

```
docker build -t myimage .
```

Then, we can check the image is in the local image store:

```
docker images
```

Please refer to the freqtrade DockerFile https://github.com/freqtrade/freqtrade/blob/develop/Dockerfile